# ☺ isn't rendering in mobile versions

Tags: html, unicode

How do i get the special character `☺` of a smiley face to render correctly in the mobile browsers?

`<li><a href="http://goo.gl/GjxlI" title="Me, Smiling" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: 20px;"> ☺</span></a></li>`

It appears on most browsers as `[ ]`

Comment: How does it render then?

Comment: Chrome renders the smiley in the text ok, but gets the square in the title bar. I wonder why.

Comment: Square means that the font used doesn't support the character

Comment: Have you tried the HTML entity `&#9786;`?

Comment: Just tried. &#9786; works on iphone, but on android (2.3.6) it shows as a square

Comment: @asawyer what version are you running? Chrome 21 beta renders the smiley face correctly in the title bar for me.

Comment: @TylerCrompton Version 21.0.1180.79 m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is a lack of that character in a font, not a character encoding problem.

There is nothing you can do about this, short of trying to use your own custom font (you may have mobile browser support problems).  I would suggest using an image instead, if possible.