# ÆØÅ shows as diamond question marks

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am almost sorry for asking this question, as I have plowed through most of the similar topics, and see how many people before me that have asked it. In short, here is my code, and it still shows those darned diamond question marks.  This is the entire header html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="nb" lang="nb">

<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="turn.js"></script>

<title>MY TITLE HERE</title>

</head>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  The documents are made in Coda, which after some google'ing has led me to believe automatically encodes in UTF-8.

Comment: Is you text in Josefin Sans? Does it work in another font?

Comment: The diamond-questionmark is printed for any character that doesn't exist in the font you're trying to use.  Most fonts only support a subset of all possible unicode characters -- you need to pick a font that supports all the characters you wish to use.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994510/isnt-rendering-in-mobile-versions/11994663#11994663

Comment: @minitech: Josefin Sans, yes. But same issue with all fonts.

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  The font supports the Latin extended letters (ÆØÅ++)

Comment: @Brad:  Thanks, but the link information seems as more work then it should be, and most likely issues with letter spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is in fact encoded in ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252 or something similar. Declaring UTF-8 will thus break all non-Ascii characters.

You should open the file in your authoring tool and save it as UTF-8 encoded. If this cannot be done, change the `meta` tag to declare `windows-1252` instead of `UTF-8`.

I’m assuming that the server does not declare the encoding in HTTP headers. If it does, then you will need to make the actual encoding to match the header.

Comment: Going into "Coda" preferences it claims to have it's "Default File Encoding" set to Unicode(UTF-8) with Default Line Endings as  Mac OS X / Unix.

This leads me to believe that the document will be saved in UTF-8 encoding, or am I way off?

But, even after trying `windows-1252`I have issues, alas the diamond boxed question marks are gone, but annoyingly replaced with a shorter and slightly elevated "-".   Perhaps I will try a new coding program and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I uploaded the site where the actual problem is, hopefully some of you can have a quick look, and see if you have the same issues.  The current `meta`tag is declaring `windows-1252`.
(I know there are some other issues on this site for now)
The Problem is the two first options in the menu, it is supposed to show "RØTTER" and "11ÅR" - but now showing "R-TTER" and "11R"
http://www.fredberentsen.com/M-webside/index.html

Comment: On the page, there are hex codes 81 and AF where the letters should appear. The encoding is thus neither utf-8 nor ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252.

Comment: Thank you for knowing this!  I might just make a bonfire out of my hardware and go to bed again!  Upon refreshing FileZilla, I noticed this flying by: "Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters."  I might have to chat with the server provider (one.com).

Comment: Figured it out!!!  Stupid programming language was set to Western (MAC OS Roman).   Thank you all.

Comment: I encounter the same issue. However, in one page, the symbol is showing and in another page the symbol changed to diamond question marks. Changing utf-8 to windows-1252 doesn't work for my case, any idea what could possibly wrong?